# Intance refresh does not set up new instances in new subnets

Tags: aws-auto-scaling

I have an auto scaling group with 2 instances and i changed the subnets to two private subnets instead of using the two public ones.

Doing in instance refresh did not start any new instances in my new subnets. Why is that?